# How to refer to amino acids by their single-letter abbreviations in ChemicalData[]?

Tags: curated-data, chemistry

`ChemicalData["AminoAcids"]` returns the 20 amino acids. There are some properties available, like the molar mass:

```
ChemicalData["L-Alanine", "MolarMass"]
```

Is there a way to refer to amino-acids using their single-letter abbreviation? For example, `L-Alanine` is `A`. I know that

```
ChemicalData["A", "MolarMass"]
```

is too ambiguous. I also tried

```
ChemicalData[{"AminoAcids", A"}, "MolarMass"]
```

but it doesn't work.

The problem is that I have a protein sequence in single-letter form and I want to calculate its molar mass. I could build a dictionary by hand to translate from single-letter to full amino-acid name. But I'm wondering if it is implemented already.

Comment: Of course, to get the true molecular weight of a peptide with your proposal, you will have to subtract an appropriate multiple of 18 (that is, water's molecular weight) from the result of adding up the molecular weights of the component amino acids.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I guess the only way is to build up a rule to do the conversion for you. I've done just that, so here it is:

```
abb = {"A" -> "L-Alanine", "R" -> "L-Arginine", "N" -> "LAsparagine", 
       "D" -> "LAsparticAcid", "C" -> "LCysteine", "E" -> "L-GlutamicAcid",
       "Q" -> "L-Glutamine", "G" -> "Glycine", "H" -> "L-Histidine", 
       "I" -> "L-Isoleucine", "L" -> "L-Leucine", "K" -> "Lysine", 
       "M" -> "L-Methionine", "F" -> "L-Phenylalanine", "P" -> "L-Proline",
       "S" -> "L-Serine", "T" -> "L-Threonine", "W" -> "L-Tryptophan", 
       "Y" -> "L-Tyrosine", "V" -> "L-Valine", "U" -> "Selenocysteine", 
       "O" -> "LPyrrolysine" }
```

Now let's use it:

```
Map[ChemicalData[#, "MolarMass"] &, {"Y", "A", "R", "F"} /. abb]

(* {181.189g/mol, 89.0932g/mol, 174.201g/mol, 165.189g/mol} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was about to do that. Just wanted to be sure it wasn't already implemented in Mathematica's data.

Comment: @becko. Well, I'm glad I saved you the trouble. :)

Comment: If need be, one can also add entries for selenocysteine and pyrrolysine.

Comment: @J.M. I just added them. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer (community wiki)

Thanks to [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) for a correction to the 3-letter abbreviations.

```
aaList = {"LAlanine", "LCysteine", "LAsparticAcid", "LGlutamicAcid","LPhenylalanine", "Glycine", "LHistidine", "LIsoleucine", "LLysine", "LLeucine", "LMethionine", "LAsparagine","LPyrrolysine", "LProline", "LGlutamine", "LArginine", "LSerine", "LThreonine", "Selenocysteine", "LValine", "LTryptophan","LTyrosine"};
```

Standard Amino Acids (22) incorporated on ribosome

```
stdAA = ChemicalData[#, "StandardName"] & /@ aaList;
```

and

```
nameAA = ChemicalData[#, "Name"] & /@ aaList;
```

Accepted Amino Acid 1-Letter and 3-Letter Abbreviations

```
oneLetterAA = Delete[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], {{2}, {10}, {24}, {26}}];
threeLetterAA = ReplacePart[StringTake[#, 3] & /@ (StringTrim[#, "L"] & /@ stdAA) /. {"Pyr" -> 
 "Pyl", "Sel" -> "Sec", "Iso" -> "Ile", "Try" -> "Trp"}, {12 -> 
"Asn", 15 -> "Gln"}]
```

1-Letter to Standard

```
oneToStdAA = Thread[oneLetterAA -> stdAA]
```

> {A->LAlanine,C->LCysteine,D->LAsparticAcid,E->LGlutamicAcid,F->LPhenylalanine,
>
> G->Glycine,H->LHistidine,I->LIsoleucine,K->LLysine,L->LLeucine,
>
> M->LMethionine,N->LAsparagine,O->LPyrrolysine,P->LProline,Q->LGlutamine,R->LArginine,
>
> S->LSerine,T->LThreonine,U->Selenocysteine,V->LValine,W->LTryptophan,
>
> Y->LTyrosine}

3-Letter to Standard

```
threeToStdAA = Thread[threeLetterAA -> stdAA]
```

> {Ala->LAlanine,Cys->LCysteine,Asp->LAsparticAcid,Glu->LGlutamicAcid,
>
> Phe->LPhenylalanine,Gly->Glycine,His->LHistidine,Ile->LIsoleucine,
>
> Lys->LLysine,Leu->LLeucine,Met->LMethionine,Asn->LAsparagine,
>
> Pyl->LPyrrolysine,Pro->LProline,Gln->LGlutamine,Arg->LArginine,Ser->LSerine,
>
> Thr->LThreonine,Sec->Selenocysteine,Val->LValine,Trp->LTryptophan,
>
> Tyr->LTyrosine}

#### Example One

```
Transpose[{oneLetterAA, threeLetterAA, stdAA, nameAA, 
 Map[ChemicalData[#, "MolarMass"] &, oneLetterAA /. oneToStdAA]}] //
 TableForm
```

[image]

#### Example Two. The molecular weight of [bovine serum albumin](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/3336842?report=genpept) (bsa)

```
aaToMMass = Thread[oneLetterAA -> Map[ChemicalData[#, "MolarMass"] &, oneLetterAA /. oneToStdAA]];
```

Import Sequence

```
importedSequence = Import["http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=
protein&id=3336842&rettype=fasta&retmode=text", "Data"]; 

{bsaSequenceHeading, bsaSequenceData} = {First@#, Rest@#} &@importedSequence;

bsaSequenceHeading
```

> >gi|3336842|emb|CAA76847.1| bovine serum albumin [Bos taurus]

Sequence molar mass of bovine serum albumin

```
bsaMolarMass = Total[# /. aaToMMass]  - (Length@# - 1) ChemicalData["Water", "MolarMass"] &@
Flatten@Characters@StringReplace[bsaSequenceData, Whitespace -> ""]
```

> 69323.  g/mol
>
> <s>69332.0 g/mol</s>

Thanks to [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) for suggesting `ChemicalData["Water", "MolarMass"]`.  I had originally just multiplied by 18.

If "MolecularMass" is preferred to "MolarMass" (see [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/38083/1791))

```
aaMolecularMass = Thread[ChemicalData["AminoAcids", "StandardName"] ->  
ChemicalData["AminoAcids", "MolecularMass"]];

bsaMolecularMass = Total[# /. aaMolecularMass]  - (Length@# - 1) ChemicalData["Water", 
  "MolecularMass"] &@(Flatten@
 Characters@StringReplace[bsaSequenceData, Whitespace -> ""] /. 
oneToStdAA)
```

> 69323. u

As pointed out by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m), an advantage of using "MolecularMass" is that the result may converted to kilodaltons

```
UnitConvert[%, "Kilodaltons"]
```

> 69.323 kDa

#### Example Three

Putting it all together:

```
importedSequence2 = Import["http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=
protein&id=AAS66653&rettype=fasta&retmode=text", "Data"];

Flatten@{{UnitConvert[#, "Kilodaltons"] &@(Total[# /. aaMolecularMass] 
- (Length@# - 1) ChemicalData["Water","MolecularMass"]), Quantity[Length@# , 
IndependentUnit["amino acids"]]} &@(Flatten@Characters@StringReplace[#, Whitespace -> ""] /. 
oneToStdAA) &@Rest@# , First@#} &@importedSequence2
```

> 51.2581kDa, 472 amino acids,
>
> >gi|45479207|gb|AAS66653.1| variable surface glycoprotein [Trypanosoma evansi]

Comment: Asparagine and glutamine should be "Asn" and "Gln", respectively; otherwise, nicely done. :)

Comment: I was going to suggest a further unit change to kilodaltons to match tradition with proteins of that size, but it seems *Mathematica* treats `"Kilodaltons"` as a unit of mass as opposed to molecular weight. How annoying... anyway, for readability, using `(Length[#] - 1) ChemicalData["Water", "MolarMass"]` to remove the equivalent amount of water might be better.

Comment: @ J.M.  That is a nice suggestion.  Have updated accordingly. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Ah, so `"MolecularMass"` is the one that can be converted to kilodaltons! Now it is clear...