# Why are Dalton and Grams / Moles not equivalent units?

Tags: units, chemistry

The following code throws an error:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity["Daltons"], "Grams"/"Moles"]
```

Why?

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113107) to an older question by the OP has an apropos discussion.

Comment: @J.M. I had forgotten that :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [nikie](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/242/nikie) has [pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154848/106), *Mathematica* considers the [Dalton](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1016/0307-4412(89)90145-3/pdf) to be a unit of mass. It is also synonymous with the [unified atomic mass unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_atomic_mass_unit) (u).

```
UnitConvert[Quantity["Daltons"], "u"]
```

> 1.0000000u

*Mathematica* also distinguishes between [Molecular Mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_mass) and [Molar Mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass) and the default unit for `MolecularMass` appears to be unified atomic mass unit (u) rather than the Dalton

```
{#, UnitConvert[#, "Daltons"]}& @ ChemicalData["Water", "MolecularMass"]
```

> {18.0153u,18.0153daltons}

Compare with:

```
{#, UnitConvert[#, "Daltons"], UnitConvert[#, "u"]}& ChemicalData["Water", "MolarMass"]
```

{18.0153g/mol,1.08491*10^25daltons/mol,1.08491*10^25u/mol}

In addition:

```
{#, UnitConvert[#, "Daltons"]} &@ ChemicalData["Water", "MolecularMass"]    // QuantityUnit
```

> $\{\text{AtomicMassUnit},\text{Daltons}\}$

and

```
{#, UnitConvert[#, "Daltons"], UnitConvert[#, "u"]} & @
ChemicalData["Water", "MolarMass"] // QuantityUnit
```

> $\left\{\frac{\text{Grams}}{\text{Moles}},\frac{\text{Daltons}}{\text{Moles}},\frac{\text{AtomicMassUnit}}{\text{Moles}}\right\}$

There is also `Kilodaltons`, of course:

```
ProteinData[6400, "MolecularWeight"] // UnitConvert[#, "Kilodaltons"] &
```

> 33.02400kDa

Despite the wikipedia [quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass), I don't think biochemists use the definition  1 Da = 1 g/mol. For a good discussion of the Dalton and the confusion it can cause, see *To land on a dalton* by Susan Dewhurst, available [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1016/0307-4412(89)90145-3/pdf)

Comment: I upvoted for the article, thanks for linking to it!

Answer (score 6):

I never heard the unit "dalton" before, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_atomic_mass_unit), 1 dalton equals $1.66053904\times 10^{−27}\, \mathrm{kg}$. That's what Mathematica says, too:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity["Daltons"], "Kilograms"]
```

> 1.6605390*10^-27 kg

But it's weird that neither `UnitConvert` nor `UnitSimplify` seem to know that *mol* is a dimensionless unit, so it could be replaced with a dimensionless constant.

If I explicitly ask for a unitless value using `UnitSimplify` with the option `UnityDimensions`, I get 1 as a result, which seems strange to me:

```
UnitSimplify[Quantity[1, "Moles"], UnityDimensions -> {"AmountUnit"}]
```

> 1

Comment: See also this, under [Molar Mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass): "The dalton, symbol Da, is also sometimes used as a unit of molar mass, especially in biochemistry, with the definition 1 Da = 1 g/mol, despite the fact that it is strictly a unit of mass"

Comment: @b3m2a1 Ah, that's the answer then. Mathematica is using the definition of Dalton as a mass unit.

Comment: I wouldn't like my moles to be simplified away as dimensionless constants (even if they are). I prefer Mathematica to carry them around.

Comment: @becko Which is technically its definition. Same thing happens with Wavenumbers and energy.

Comment: *Da* is commonly used in the (biological) mass spectrometry world (that I was in for about 19 years),

Comment: As @Peter says, it's a common unit in biochemistry; one would often see entries in the PDB giving the molecular mass in *kilo*daltons.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are:

```
   << Units`
    Convert[1 Dalton, Gram/Mole]
```

Comment: It should be noted that the above uses the old Units package, which is obsolete.